# I am not getting any output in web scraping using beautiful soup and python and

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am using python, beautiful soup and lxml to extract some some information from the site but I am not getting any output as well as any errors. Here's the code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_file = requests.get('https://www.covid19india.org').text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file)

states = soup.find_all('div',class_='state-name fadeInUp')

print(states)
```

Comment: Please [edit] the code in your question. 1. [Format](/help/format) it correctly using code-fences. 2. We want only code. Please remove all line numbers and extraneous text that would prevent a reader from pasting your code into their environment easily. See [mre]. Since you're new here, you should also take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded from external source via JavaScript, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. You can use this example how to load the data via `requests` module:

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://api.covid19india.org/v4/min/data.min.json"

data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some data
print(
    "{:<3} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format(
        "STATE", "CONFIRMED", "DECEASED", "RECOVERED", "TESTED", "VACCINATED"
    )
)
for k, v in data.items():
    print(
        "{:<5} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format(
            k,
            v["total"]["confirmed"],
            v["total"]["deceased"],
            v["total"]["recovered"],
            v["total"]["tested"],
            v["total"]["vaccinated"],
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
STATE CONFIRMED  DECEASED   RECOVERED  TESTED     VACCINATED
AN    6789       98         6417       381349     117175    
AP    1542079    9904       1323019    18435149   7857020   
AR    23159      89         20339      525589     318092    
AS    359640     2588       302889     9982316    3620118   
BR    681199     4339       627548     28735144   9363116   
CH    57737      680        51382      477484     302008    
CT    941366     12391      852529     8508024    6812740   
DL    1412959    22831      1354445    18595993   4970999   
DN    9822       4          9167       72410      133590    
GA    143192     2302       121562     778828     466488    
GJ    780471     9469       686581     20763702   15176798  
HP    175384     2638       141198     1806900    2303829   
HR    728607     7317       666893     8585262    5198191   
JH    324884     4714       293659     7998874    3790724   
JK    263905     3465       210547     8140036    2905270   
KA    2367742    24207      1829276    28453442   11799162  
KL    2293633    6995       1979919    18555023   8597282   
LA    17025      172        15264      237486     128352    
LD    5756       20         4051       108986     29058     
MH    5527092    86618      5070801    32441776   20465193  
ML    27755      414        20480      527955     424005    
MN    42565      661        35606      675645     403249    
MP    757119     7394       682100     9148503    9533515   
MZ    9732       30         7450       354526     301219    
NL    19593      258        14149      207977     246656    
OR    668422     2483       567382     11118984   6964278   
PB    528676     12888      452318     8556117    4519318   
PY    93167      1295       73936      971544     239864    
RJ    903418     7475       764137     10118617   15708235  
SK    12527      220        8916       108170     230968    
TG    547727     3085       500247     14402251   5522361   
TN    1770988    19598      1476761    25949517   7280700   
TR    44356      452        37037      836629     1527207   
TT    26285069   295508     23059017   324417870  191879503 
UP    1659212    18760      1534176    46111719   15813654  
UT    307566     5600       233266     4443937    2743665   
WB    1229805    14054      1083570    11786397   12932811
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this issue because you are not getting the same response from the site as you recieve it from the site.
Hint:
you can use this to display it on your output terminal

```py
from IPython.core.display import display,HTML

display(HTML(html_file))
```